# Two chords $AB$ and $CD$ intersects

Tags: geometry

Two chords $AB$ and $CD$ intersects at point $P$ at right angle. $M$ is mid point of $BD$. $MP$ is produced to $N$ on $AC$. Prove that $PN\perp AC$

[image]

My Attempt 
$\angle APN=\angle MPB$

$\angle BPD=90$.

Now what should I do next?

Comment: Let $Q$ be the midpoint of $DP$. Then $DQM,DPM,APC$ and $ANP$ are similar triangles.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$M$ is the centre of the circumcircle of $DPB$, so $MP=MB$ and hence $\angle MPB=\angle DBP$. Hence $\angle DPM=90^o-\angle DBP$, but $\angle DPM=\angle NPC$, so $\angle NPC=90^o-\angle DBP=90^o-\angle DCN$. The angles in $PNC$ must add to $180^o$, so $\angle PNC=90^o$.

Comment: How do you get the idea of drawing another circle with Centre M.?

Comment: @user335710 With geometry problems like these, you try five or ten different things and see which ones turn out to work. In this case, drawing a circle with center $M$ and radius $MP$ was a thing that worked.

Comment: Is there any alternative to this or this is only the method?

Comment: @user335710 Yes, Arthur is correct, it is hard to get good at geometry problems without a lot of practice. Other methods. I have no idea. Usually there are many ways of solving problems. But I was brought up on contest maths. You have no time to search for the best idea, you grab the first thing you can find that works!

Comment: @almagest, what is your Facebook I'd? Could you please provide me that?